# MVC: How to insert items in a grid without refreshing the whole page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this view where I create a new company that gets added to the database.
The view is in 2 sections, leftside and rightside.
In the rightside I want to input the trades for that company.
A company can have 1 or more trade and this includes 1 primary trade, and 0 to many other trades.
When the user adds in the other trades, each trade will be added to a list underneath. I have NOT put in the code for this yet. For each trade in the list, he can have the option of removing it.
When he has entered all the details, he clicks submit and all the data is saved in the database.
Now I am thinking of putting in a partial view for the other trades, but I am wondering how I can do this, and every time a trade is selected from autocomplete, the data is posted to a controller method and the partial view is return.
But this will clear the data in the leftside section.
So how should I do this?
My view looks like

```
@model SCD.ViewModels.SubcontractorViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create Subcontractor</legend>
        <section class="wrapper">
            <section class="leftside">
                <table class="formTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="leftCell">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subcontractor.CompanyName)</td>
                        <td class="rightCell">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subcontractor.CompanyName, new { @style = "width: 300px;" })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="leftCell">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressViewModel.Address1)</td>
                        <td class="rightCell">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AddressViewModel.Address1, new { @style = "width: 300px;" })</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;" class="rightCell"><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div style="float: left">@Html.ActionLink(" ", "List", null, new { @class = "buttonBackToList" })</div>
            </section>
            <section class="rightside">
                <table class="formTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="leftCell">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrimaryTrade)</td>
                        <td class="rightCell"><input type="search" name="searchPrimaryTrade" id="searchPrimaryTrade" data-scd-autocomplete="@Url.Action("AutocompletePrimaryTrade", "DataService")" style = "width: 300px;"/>
                            <input type="button" id="ResetPrimaryTrade" value="Reset"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="leftCell">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherTrades)</td>
                        <td class="rightCell"><input type="search" name="searchOtherTrade" id="searchOtherTrade" data-scd-autocomplete="@Url.Action("AutocompleteOtherTrade", "DataService")" style = "width: 300px;"/>
                            <input type="button" id="ResetOtherTrade" value="Reset"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </section>
        </section>

    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is your answer, Whenever you do not want to reload the page then using client side ajax to communicate with the server is the only option.

I would use jQuery or to add the rows via ajax which will insert them into your database and return the populated model again and return this as a `PartialView()`. Your ajax would then `onSuccess`: replace your tableID with the returned results.

So your jQuery would be something like:

```
$('.rightside').children('.formTable').replaceWith(theReturnedPartialFromAjaxCall);
```

If you are adding a dynamic row there are two options:

On adding a row you can call an ajax request which will also add a blank row to the database and then repopulate your model and return the Partial View. This will now have the model binding in place on the new blank row, deleting the blank row or any row can also be done by ajax as the row now has an ID. Make sure however you put the ID as a hidden field in when you loop through each row.

OR (not the preferred way but probably what you will need to do as you have to perform the save)

You can capture the form collection in the save, if there are multiple rows then store this in an array

```
public ActionResult Save(MyModel model, FormCollection frm) {
    String[] name = frm["name"].Split(',');
}
```

I don't like this way as it is prone to error and the first method will allow you to bind MVC's model validation

Comment: OK I think this is good, however I cannot implement this. The reason is because of how the information is input. I select a trade from autocomplete, and this adds a row to the grid underneath. Only when I click on submit does the whole form get posted back and the data saved.

Comment: @arame3333 - when you say you add a row, this I assume is done by javascript, when you add the row is it possible to save a "Blank Row to the database and then reload the Partial View? This will then give you your model mapping fields With an ID to update etc. Or you can capture the form collection in your Post to perform the save

Comment: although you are mostly right, the key bit you have got wrong is that I cannot save the row to the database because the company has not been created yet. I could store it to session object, but I am reluctant to do that.

Comment: So it is only when I click the submit button that everything gets saved to the database.